# Is it possible to change the default iCloud Drive location on macOS from the user’s Library directory to an external drive?

Tags: macos, icloud

I assume that, since it's all encrypted, they won't allow it. My startup drive is minimal and soldered, so I'd like to move it so I can keep a full downloaded copy of my iCloud Drive (that gets backed up to Time Machine).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can move almost any directory to any location, the trick is not to use the macOS-only Alias, rather the Unix sub-systems SymLink feature. This works with any application, terminal command and even the macOS itself.

You can only create SymLinks in Terminal, so if you aren't comfortable using shell commands this may not be for you. Though it's actually pretty easy.

```
ln -s /path/to/original /path/to/link
```

So basically you would want to move the folder to where you want it, making sure that the original location doesn't have anything by that name. For example I moved my Dropbox folder to a larger external drive. Once it was copied, I turned off Dropbox and deleted the original dropbox folder. Then...

```
 ln -s /Volumes/ExternalHD/Dropbox ~/Dropbox
```

Then I launched Dropbox and it happily followed the SymLink in my home folder to the folder on the external HD.

You can do this with any folder on your HD just remember that the full path to the **new location** comes **first** followed by the old location.

Note that I have not tried this with iCloud Drive. I would bet that you would have to turn off iCloud drive first (having already copied your files to the new location) so that you can remove the iCloud drive folder and create the SymLink without the iCloud processes preventing you from moving/removing folders it needs to work.

So while this *should* work. Back up your iCloud Drive folder before proceeding, as I have not tried this. In theory it should work.

Comment: This *might* work, but iCloud might not allow that even if you think a symlink would work.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'll dig into this!

Answer (score 0):

The proposed SymLink solution as presented below, does not work for iCloud, stopping the iCloud Drive and logging out of Apple ID, and moving the iCloud folder to wherever you want to relocate it, and then using the terminal command provided below to create the SymLink (pointing to the new location of the iCloud Drive folder which was in the "~/library/Mobile Documents" directory, and then relogging in to your Apple ID and the iCloud drive, the MacOS will delete the newly created Symlink and will replace it back with the folder named "Mobile Documents" inside the "~/library" directory.
Now, I tried it and I know that the iCloud files are stored in the folder ~/Library/Mobile Documents. (The tilde symbol is a shortcut for your user folder.)
So, trying to move the "Mobile Documents" folder and creating a Symlink inside the "~/Library/" pointing to the new location does not work for iCloud!
I hope this is clear!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This is not a discussion forum. Therefore this answer should be a comment. And its a giant monolith. I  was unable to split it into sentences and paragraphs.  To improve it, please edit and use shorter sentences, AND provide a solution.